# Why converting to JSON a hash I initialized yield a null?

Tags: json, hash, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to build a hash in order to later output is as JSON (and ultimately import it to be reused by a a script). This is part of my static site built with `jekyll`.

Following the [documentation on Expressions and Variables](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#expressions-and-variables), I created a file with

```
---
---
{% assign aaa['bbb'] = 'xxx' %}
{{ aaa | jsonify }}
```

This was compiled by `jekyll` to a `null` (as if the hash was not initialized). **Why is it so?**

Comment: please can you provide a direct link to documentation about the jsonify filter.  I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly the documentation is talking about reading hash or arrays, not writing.

The only thing you can write from liquid is arrays.

- create an empty array : `{% assign my-array = "" | split: "/" %}{{
  y-array | inspect }}`
- store with push or shift `{% assign my-array = my-array | push: anything %}
  = empty-array }}`, where **anything** can be a string, an integer, a hash or an array.